# How to restrict kubernetes dashboard to one namespace

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I have setup a microk8s k8s cluster.

I have enabled the kubernetes dashboard in the kube-system namespace.

I have a namespace called XXX and I would like to show this namespace in the dashboard and only this namespace.

I have created a service account, secret, role and rolebinding:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: dashboard-account
  namespace: xxx


kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: dashboard-role
  namespace: xxx
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]


apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: role-binding-dashboard-account
  namespace: xxx
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: dashboard-role
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: dashboard-account
  namespace: xxx



apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: dashboard-account-secret
  namespace: xxx
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: dashboard-account
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
```

Now I need to get some sort of token(or kubeconfig?).
I have a k8s-client called Lens and in that one I can see this:
[image: Screen shot from Lens]

If I use the token visible in the image to connect to the dashboard I see all namespaces. Same goes if I use the kubeconfig in the image I also see all namespaces.

How can I restrict the dashboard in just showing the namespace xxx?

Answer (score 0):

do you see all namespaces from the microk8s cluster ?

if it s the case, check dashboard-account permission/role.

Comment: Yes I see all namespaces. How do you mean "check dashboard-account permission/role". Where should I look and what should I do?

Comment: you configured the dashboard-account to have access to all the namespace of your cluster, you need to restric only to the namespace you want .
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/

Comment: I have added all the files that I have used in the post. The service-account, the role, the rolebinding and the secret. Could you tell me which of the files I need to change and what to change? I have set the namespace in every location possible I think, or have i missed it somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

check

> kubectl get clusterrolebinding -o yaml | grep -B 5 -A 5 'dashboard-account'

if you find one this mean your dashboard-account have some permission on the cluster.
if you find nothing check if they are some rolebinding for other namespaces linked to the dashboard-account.

> kubectl get rolebinding --all-namespaces -o yaml | grep -B 5 -A 5 'dashboard-account'

if you find nothing i don t know. The access are defined by role and rolebinding.

you can try to check the service account part :
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/

in this one they are a some part for ServiceAcccount permissions too
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/

Comment: Apparently I had forgotten to enabled RBAC for the cluster...when I did that it started working.

Comment: it happens :) .  Godd job